# Should I use an array to store the answers to multiple choice a,b,c,d?

Tags: c, arrays, multiple-choice

C Program
I'm a complete beginner. I want to make a multiple choice vocabulary practice program for my students. I DO NOT WANT to create 4 separate variables a,b,c,d.
How can I use an array? Or what is a better way to store the 4 characters a,b,c,d and refer to them each time I want the program to check whether the question is correct or not. Please have a look at the code I am using so far. Any help I woul really appreciate. Thank you.

```
int main (void)
{    
    char s;
    const char *answer[3];
    answer[0]="a";
    answer[1]="b";
    answer[2]="c";
    answer[3]="d";
    int i=0;
    float count;


    printf (" Listo para empezar?\n\n Please type 's' for si or 'n' for no.\n");
    scanf ("%c",&s);
          if (s='s'){
                printf ("Bueno. Ya Empezamos!");
                }   

    for (count=0;count<=4;count++){
        printf ("1.Que significa la palabra 'conocer'\n");
        printf ("a.\t to like b.\t to know\t c. to do\t d. to eat\n");

        /*Where I need help"*/
        scanf ("%s",&answer);
        if (answer =answer[1])
        {
        printf ("Correcto!\n");
        }
       else {
       printf ("Equivocado!\n 'conocer'significa: to know\n")
       }`enter code here`
```

Comment: `const char *answer[3];` You're declaring an array of `const char*`.

Comment: could you explain a little more. i don't get what you mean

Comment: to be able to reference `answer[0]`, `answer[1]`, `answer[2]` and `answer[3]` (so, an array of **four(4) elements**) you have to declare it as `const char *answer[4]`, (four(4) elements)

Answer (score 1):

Declaration of the array as `char answer[4]` should be enough instead of `const char *answer[3]`. Arrays are indexed starting from **0** to **n-1**, where n is the number of items you want to hold. So when you are declaring an array it should be of size n and while you are accessing some value say at its i th position its index is actually i-1, which you have already done correctly.

Next since the user will be entering a single character as input.

`scanf("%c",&x)` should work fine for you.

By doing `scanf("%s",&answer)` you will be overwriting the values you have stored in your actual answer array. So you should take the input in a separate character variable say `x`, just like I have done in the above example. Then you can simply compare the value of `x` in the `if` statement as `if(x == answer[1])`.

Although I am not sure how you will be generating the questions and altering the correct option, so that part of the code for checking the correct answer will depend on that.

Comment: helpful information. but it still give s an error. it says invalid conversion from const char to char.